# How can I change the regular ctrl commands to accept super instead?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys

Macintosh, I've discovered, has the right idea in that they use the apple key instead of <kbd>ctrl</kbd> in the copy, paste, select all, etc commands. This is extremely useful in the terminal, where <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> is already predefined to be `stop`, but where I also need to copy and paste text. Is there a way to switch all the normal gui shortcuts to <kbd>super</kbd> instead of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>?